# Laravel image issue

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

im trying to make a profile view for my users, but having an issue when showing the profile photo, because i get the box such like its waiting for the foto but it doesn't shows it, here is the code:

@include('layouts.header')
@include('layouts.navbar')

```
<div class="media-body">
    <a class="pull-left">
    <img class="media-object" src="{{Auth::user()->avatar}}" alt = "Foto de perfil">
    </a>
    <h3>{{Auth::user()->name}}</h3><br>
    <h5>Email: {{Auth::user()->email}}</h5>
    <h5>Telefono: {{Auth::user()->phone}}</h5>
</div>


@include('layouts.footer')
```

i have the images saved in public/images/

Comment: Does **{{Auth::user()->avatar}}** represent the full URL or just the filename i.e. avatar.jpg?

Comment: true, but still dont working with this:

<img class="media-object" src="public/images/.Auth::user()->avatar" alt = "Foto de perfil"

Answer (score 1):

You may try this (Assumed `Auth::user()->avatar` returns only the file name like - `image.png`):

```
<img
class="media-object"
src="{{asset('images') . '/' . Auth::user()->avatar }}"
alt = "Foto de perfil"
/>
```

Comment: This should fix the problem. Documentation link here (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset). It should also be pointed out that "public" should not be a part of URLs/paths accessed through HTTP.

Comment: still doesn't work, if i go to inspect element on chrome it gives me this problem:
GET http://localhost:8000/images/ 404 (Not Found)
it seems that it don't get to the photos, and this its not going to the url it should